# Best way to detect an unknown device to alert the user

Tags: javascript, java, security, authentication

So I'm working on adding an alert to our web application when a user logs in from an unknown device. I'm trying to figure out the best way to actually detect the unknown device, and what the industry standard is.

I initially thought about using cookies, but the user would still get the warning if they used a different browser or simply cleared their cookies. My second thought was storing their IP in the database and checking against that, but their IP could change as well.

Any ideas? What do companies like Facebook, Google, etc. do when they generate these warnings?

Comment: You log in. They store the device and flag it as trusted when you tell them it is ok or do not react to their "You signed in from an uknown device" for a certain amount of time but still use the service in a normal manner

Comment: @mplungjan So I'm guessing they store the device in the database then? What do they use the uniquely identify *that* device

Comment: Cookies are mostly used for that, counting another browser as different device.

Comment: they can use a [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) - they will not use cookies (at least not only cookies) since they are stored on the device and not be useful on a different device or if the cookies are deleted

Answer (score 1):

Generally, login systems keep a track of the following

1. user location (IP Address)
2. device details - os, client (browser/mobile app)

Whenever a user logs in, the system checks for these combinations. If any of the information has changed, the system will send a notification to the user.

Check [Baeldung's article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-new-device-location) for reference